# Display Confirm Dialog from CodeBehind using MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

We got a big project with lots logic checks. For example, when they click "save" on this certain form, it does about 3 - 4 different confirm message. These confirm dialogs should be displayed from code behind.

What are some ways this can be done?
I know I can use ajax parameters to send in values like param = { areYouSure: "Yes", alsoDeleteContract: "No", continueIfError: "Yes" }

Is there any more efficient way? 
Or is there a way I can call the code straight from the controller? wait for the dialog result and then continue with the result.

We got SignalR on our project so this is kind of what I was thinking:

```
public ActionResult controllerMethod()
{
    var result = signalRHub.CallQuePopupTask(task, connectionID, CurrentUser);
    if result == "yes" { ... }
    else { return "don't activate" }
}

public static void CallQuePopupTask(Types.CallQuePopupTask task, string connectionID, User user)
{
    var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<signalRHub>();
    // Will display a confirm dialog to client and wait for client to click yes or no
    var dialogResult = hub.Clients.Client(connectionID).callQuePopupDialogResult();
    return dialogResult;
}
```

Comment: If this is a web project why would you not use Javascript with confirm box?

Comment: Because there are complex logic checks that javascript would not be able to complete. For example, calling an entity service, validating the entity, and displaying something like "This entity might not have your equipments, do you still want to use this?"

Comment: You should be able to simply attach a `confirm` to your front-end code.  Then when you hit yes, it actually hits the controller as it should.

Comment: Yes Greg, but remember there are 3 - 4 dialog. That includes complex checks. Please look at my previous comment for an example.

Comment: Then you should do proper view data abstraction.  For each UI change, the Controller should perform logic before loading another View.  Otherwise your fighting the stateless premise of MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the server needs to handle these checks, then just pass it the data and let it do its thing. All you need is some simple AJAX and standard JavaScript confirm dialogs. For example, the user hits submit. You catch the form submit event and send an AJAX call to an action that handles the first check. That action will then do the check and return an JSON object that contains some boolean or something that tells you whether the user needs to confirm something. If so, then you present the confirm dialog and wait for the user's response. Rinse and repeat for the other checks. If everything is good and/or the user has confirmed everything, then you finally let the form submit as normal.

Comment: Yea, I am aware of this method. I guess there is no other choice.